# Github Pages CSS not working on Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, github, wordpress-theming, github-pages

I have a Wordpress site I made that I’m trying to show live on Github Pages. It’s applying the static page, but the css styles are not being applied, and I can’t figure out why. Since this site is more than one page, I’m also trying to figure out how to have the other pages hosted on Github pages when they click the links on the first page.

Here’s the repo: https://github.com/sashakyunghwa/blog

Github Pages: https://sashakyunghwa.github.io/blog/

settings used in Simply Static plugin: (see images)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRA3q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBFxs.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE6Es.png)

Comment: I did point out the issue that I can't figure. I clearly stated I can't figure out why the CSS is not showing up on my Github pages.

Comment: If you can't help, don't bother leaving a comment. Thanks for your no help, move along.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense without visiting external links. By definition, that's off-topic. Your question *must* be self-contained. Also, you *haven't* clearly asked a question. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.